# how to reorder canvas elements in the dom through drag-and-drop?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, canvas, drag-and-drop

I want to allow drag-and-drop re-ordering of photoshop-like layers.

Assuming I have 3 canvas elements in the page with ids a, b and c:

```
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
<canvas id="b"></canvas>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

c is the layer "on-top" because it is defined last, and they are positioned absolutely on top of each other; how can I rearrange the elements into the order: c, a, b, where c is now behind the other layers?

```
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
<canvas id="b"></canvas>
```

I want to trigger the sorting by detecting drag-and-drop sorting of a list like this:

```
 <ul id="layers">
    <li>Layer C</li>
    <li>Layer B</li>
    <li>Layer A</li>
 </ul>
```

I can probably use jQuery ui sort to allow re-ordering of the list.  What is the easiest way to make the canvases DOM order mirror the list order?  (the mirroring is somewhat in reverse because the list with C on-top maps to canvas having C on bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to change the z-order of the canvases instead of just altering their order, or am I mistaken? Anyway, I'd suggest something like this:

```
$("#layers").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        $("canvas").detach(); // Removes all canvases
        $("#layers li").each(function() {
            // Reinsert them in the same order of your list items
            $("#" + $(this).data("canvas")).appendTo(whereYourCanvasesWere);
        });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

And in your HTML:

```
<ul id="layers">
    <li data-canvas="c">Layer C</li>
    <li data-canvas="b">Layer B</li>
    <li data-canvas="a">Layer A</li>
</ul>
```

Edit: oh, and if you want to invert the order they are placed, just use `prependTo` instead of `appendTo`.

Comment: Yes, re-ordering the z-index is probably the most efficient way instead of rearranging the dom to force a z-index change.

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the z-score is definitely the way to go.  I used a style to handle this for all the elements I care about. Here are some snippets from a recent project of mine.

Something like this:

```
// brings the focus of the selected table on the canvas to the front
function adjustFocus(event, ui) {
    // clear any old focuses
    $("#table-canvas").find(".table-view").each(function (index) {
        $(this).removeClass("table-view-focus");
    });

    // add the focus to the current table
    $(this).addClass("table-view-focus");
}
```

The class is simply:

```
.table-view-focus { z-index: 10; }
```

Adjust focus is called as the start event for draggable:

```
// make this view draggable
        tableView.draggable({
            containment: "#table-canvas",
            handle: "h3",
            start: adjustFocus,
            drag: tableViewDrag
        });
```